# Can one man count in two minyanim at same time

Tags: halacha, tefilla, number, minyan, orach-chaim

According to Halacha, if there are two minyanim  is it permissible for both of them to count one man  in a minyan at the same time? Or no, can he only count for one?

Comment: Isn't this just one minyan with 19 men?

Comment: Do you mean in one room is 9 people, and in a second room is 9 people, and this guy runs back and forth between minyanim?

Comment: A situation like that @CuriousYid